# find make target in makefile

Tags: gcc, build, makefile

I currently have this in my makefile:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include $(DEPS_debug)
-include $(DEPS_unittest)
-include $(DEPS_release)
endif
```

The `DEPS_` collections are all quite large since they are generated by `gcc`, so I'd like to only include those dependencies when absolutely necessary.

As it is now, any time I use this makefile to do anything other than cleanup, it incurs a two-second wait due to the loading of all the dependency files. Yes, it is probably unnecessarily checking a myriad of library headers for changes but I'll be damned if it doesn't work so well already that I don't want to screw with it.

I'd like to `-include` only `$(DEPS_debug)` when my make target is `debug`, etc.

Is there a better variable than `MAKECMDGOALS` I can make use of? An issue I forsee is that if I use `MAKECMDGOALS` to predicate the inclusion of my dependencies, if I later add an entry to the makefile `foo: debug release` and run `make foo` it won't load any of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you generate your dependencies?

```
gcc -M ... source.c
```

vs

```
gcc -MM ... source.c
```

The former lists the headers from `/usr/include`; the latter doesn't.

Comment: this is the format of the line I have been using: `@$(CC) $(CFLAGS_unittest) $(INCLUDE) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@) $< `

Comment: The relevant part of that is `-MM`; the `-MT` and `-MF` alter the target file included in the dependency output (instead of `file.o`) and where the output goes.  So, you're already trimming your list to exclude system headers; it just means you have vast compilation dependencies.  You should perhaps look into the usual techniques for reducing the number of dependent headers - forward declarations, and so on.

Comment: Also look at the output from GCC to ensure there aren't too many repetitions of a single file.  One of the headers I work with includes a file by different names (`../belib/../belib/../incl/machine.h`, `../incl/../incl/machine.h`, `../incl/machine.h`, and `machine.h`) because the code is apt to use `#include "../incl/machine.h"` in any of a large number of headers that use the machine configuration header.  And that was just from using `gcc -MM` on (a trivial C file that only included) the header, in the directory where the header lives.